# OData PUT to replace collection property

Tags: odata

Using the OData standard is it possible to replace collection by sending a new collection?
Scenario:
The person object contains a list Address object. I would want to replace the Address collection with a new collection.
PUT Persons(1)/Addresses
[{"city": "X", "country": "US"}, {"city": "Y", "country": "US"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box (at least for ODATAv3), as the default routing template does not expect segments after the key portion.

But you should be able to add an ODATA Action that would do what you want to achieve. Your action definition could then look similar to this:

```
var action = builder.Entity<Person>()
    .Action("Addresses")
    .Returns<bool>();
action.Parameter<Collection<CityCountryPair>>("data");
```

The type `CityCountryPair` would be a regular DTO containing your properties you want to change. Make sure this type is also registered as an EntitySet in Odata or use a plain map/dictionary with only primitive types.

The actual call to the ODATA action would then look similar to this:

```
POST http://www.example.com/api/YourEndpoint/Persons(42)/Addresses
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "data" : 
    [
      { "city" : "Berne" , "country": "CH" },
      { "city" : "Y" , "country": "CH" }
    ]
}
```

If you want to send more complex data types you can still resort to a customer JSON Deserialiser and override the default one or use a custom model binder after all.

Comment: Thanks. ODATA Action helped to get what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Is there anything else regarding your question which needs clarification? Otherwise you could mark my answer as the "accepted" answer.